# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook error in .net core

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, com-interop, .net-6.0

I have a program that accesses Outlook using the COM-object `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.

The first part of the program creates a new Outlook `Application` and fetches the `allpublicfolders` folder.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Folder allPublicFolder = 
    application
    .Session
    .GetDefaultFolder (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders) 
     as Outlook.Folder;
```

The program was originally targeting .NET Framework and was working as intended. But after I recently moved it to **.NET 6** I get an **red error line** underneath the `.Session` part.

The error message states the following:

> "Error CS1061  'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Session' and no accessible extension method 'Session' accepting a first argument of type 'Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Any ideas as to what could be causing this problem?

EDIT: After removing the second line it turns out that even the first line (new Outlook.Application()) returns an error:
"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System_ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interloop.Outlook.Application. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Element not found. (0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))"

Comment: What properties *are* available in your application object? I.e., what does IntelliSense suggest if you type `application.`? Is everything missing or just `Session`?

Comment: All properties are missing, but I still have methods and events.

Comment: How did you add the interop reference? If you added a COM reference to the Outlook object library, you may need to use the `_Application` interface rather than the `Application` interface.

Comment: @RichardDeeming yes I added a COM reference to "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library" (version 9.6). If I attempt to create a new _Application then I get the error message "Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface '_Application'".

Comment: @MadsGeltingBech How about `Outlook._Application application = new Outlook.Application();`?

Comment: @RichardDeeming Ah I get what you mean now. Unfortunately I still receive the original error - the properties are still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by missing the component [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}] in the Registry Editor.
Repairing office didn't help, but reinstalling office created the component and solved the error.

Comment: This is a well-known problem after upgrading Office applications or re-installing them. For example, see [0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08f13e9d-895c-4102-b6d9-e327af8cf8c0/0x80029c4a-typeecantloadlibrary?forum=vsto).

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried to create a console app based on .net 6 in VS2022 and don't get any problems with compiling and running the application under the debugger. Everything went well on my side. Here is my project's file content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp3</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>6</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>9</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>00062fff-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Make sure the target platform was set to `AnyCPU`.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for the heads-up.